# How do you list clients connected to OS X Server 10.8's VPN?

Tags: vpn

The 10.6 Server manual says this:

[image]

but it doesn't work on 10.8.

Even a Terminal command would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I put this command together to list connected IP address:

`ps -ef | awk '/[p]ppd/ {print substr($NF,2);}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can have full info for active connections with the command

```
sudo serveradmin com vpn:command = getConnectedUsers
```